# Performing "and" on jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery

I want to select the input element in my html with a certain `class` and `name`:

```
<input type="checkbox"  value="Delete" name="foo" class="Row0"/>
<input type="checkbox"  value="Delete" name="foo" class="Row1"/>
<input type="checkbox"  value="Delete" name="foo" class="Row2"/>
```

I know that I can combine selectors using comma as:

```
"selector1, selector2, selectorN"
```

So I write the selector as:

```
'input[name=foo]:checked,input[class=Row0]'
```

But that performs **or** on the selectors as it returns elements matching either of the above selectors.What if I want to get elements matching **all** the above selectors,i.e. perform **and** on the selectors?

Comment: `$('input.Row0[name="foo"]').filter(':checked')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add extra brackets:

```
input[name=foo][class=Row0]:checked
```

or simply use the class selector (which is essentially the same - might work better cache-wise):

```
input.Row0[name=foo]:checked
```

Means *an input field with the attribute `name` set to `foo`, the attribute `class` set to `Row0` and it must be checked.*

If you want to exclude elements, you can use the `:not` selector:

```
input[name=foo]:checked:not(.Row0)
```

Meaning *an input field with the attribute `name` set to `foo` and it must be checked, however it **cannot** have the class `Row0`.*

Comment: Agreed to your answer.But what if I want to exclude elements with class=Row0?

Comment: ah @h2ooooooo nice copypasta from my answer there

Comment: @MightyPork There's absolutely no copy pasting - At the moment I have a "3 new answers to this question" message, but if you feel like you have copyright on the class selector, I think you should sue jQuery and W3 for their CSS definition.

Comment: @MightyPork I do not believe that h2ooooooo has copied your answer as his answer appeared to before yours.

Comment: Yes, but the part with .Row0 was added like a minute after mine was sent. Whatever, I don't have a copyright on class selectors. It just looked that way.

Answer (score 2):

This is better:

```
input.Row0[name=foo]:checked
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in selector:

```
'input[name=foo][class=Row0]:checked'
```